# C# ASP.Net Menu control multiplies when click Static item (Ex. SMS)

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu

```
MenuItem menuTest2 = new MenuItem();    // Main Manu 2
menuTest2.Text = "  SMS  ";
//menuTest2.NavigateUrl = "something";
//menuTest2.Value = "something";
Menu1.Items.Add(menuTest2);

MenuItem child_SM1 = new MenuItem();
child_SM1.Text = "SMS Subcribe";
child_SM1.NavigateUrl = "~/20SMSsubscribe.aspx";
//child_SM1.Value = "something";
menuTest2.ChildItems.Add(child_SM1);

MenuItem child_SM2 = new MenuItem();
child_SM2.Text = "SMS Authorise";
child_SM2.NavigateUrl = "~/21SMSauthorise.aspx";
//child_SM2.Value = "something";
menuTest2.ChildItems.Add(child_SM2);
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Please explain your issues.

Comment: You need to actually *describe the problem* in some way.  Nobody is going to debug this for you or spend any time trying to figure out what's wrong for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use as below

```
MenuItem menuTest2 = new MenuItem();    // Main Manu 2
menuTest2.Text = "  SMS  ";
menuTest2.NavigateUrl = "javascript:void(0)";
//menuTest2.Value = "something";
Menu1.Items.Add(menuTest2);
```

The problem as I think was that the page get redirected to the same page when clicked. And as I guess the menu is created on `page load` event.

Using `menuTest2.NavigateUrl = "javascript:void(0)";` will stop the menu to postback when it is clicked.